# Verifying Oracle*Net network encryption

Tags: oracle, encryption

I've been struggling to implement Oracle's network encryption between two of my test boxes.  I think I've finally been able to do it, but I can't seem to find a way to verify that it is indeed enabled.

I know that tracing is enabled by default on the server side, but is there a command I can run on the remote sqlplus instance that will generate a trace and allow me to see if the specific sql is encrypted?  Is there a better way to test this?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5):

I too am looking for a better way to do this, but what I've found is that you can enable tracing on the client side and then search the tracefile that was created.

I have this in my client-side sqlnet.ora file:

```
DIAG_ADR_ENABLED=off
TRACE_DIRECTORY_CLIENT=/tmp
TRACE_FILE_CLIENT=nettrace
TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT=16
```

If you're running the client from the same server, you can override TNS_ADMIN to point to a different directory (you may need to copy tnsnames.ora, etc, to that directory as well).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I'm cautiously optimistic on my end at this point.  I stood up another box on the same virtual network and used Wireshark to look at two different Oracle*Net connections, one using a non-encrypted service and the other using my TCPS.  Looks like it's working, but I'm sure there has to be a better way of doing this...

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried checking the view V$SESSION_CONNECT_INFO?

Query:

```
select NETWORK_SERVICE_BANNER 
from v$session_connect_info 
where SID = sys_context('USERENV','SID');
```

Results:

```
NETWORK_SERVICE_BANNER
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Windows NT TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Oracle Advanced Security: encryption service for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Oracle Advanced Security: crypto-checksumming service for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Prod
```

If you get a row with NETWORK_SERVICE_BANNER like '%TCP/IP%', then you use TCP (without SSL)

If you get a row with NETWORK_SERVICE_BANNER like '%BEQUEATH%, then you use Bequeath (LOCAL=YES)

If you get a row with NETWORK_SERVICE_BANNER is null, then you use TCPS

For the current session, it is easier to select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','NETWORK_PROTOCOL') from dual

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Chris!  I tried running the above query on both a TCPS connection as well as a standard 1521 TCP connection.  While the results were different, both include the "encryption service" banner.  I have been able to verify with Wireshark that one of the connections is indeed not in plain-text, so I'm still at a bit of a loss here.

Answer (score 1):

[Using Network Encryption and Integrity](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/database-dbaas-cloud/csdbi/use-network-encryption-and-integrity.html) (in the Oracle Database Cloud Service documentation) shows the reason for your observation:

> If native Oracle Net encryption and integrity was not in use, the banner entries would still include entries for the available security services; that is, the services linked into the Oracle Database software. However, there would be no entries indicating the specific algorithms in use for the connection. The following output shows an example:
>
> ```
> NETWORK_SERVICE_BANNER
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
> Encryption service for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
> Crypto-checksumming service for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
> ```
>
> The following example output shows banner information for the available encryption service and the crypto-checksumming (integrity) service, including the algorithms in use:
>
> ```
> NETWORK_SERVICE_BANNER
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
> Encryption service for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
> AES256 Encryption service adapter for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
> Crypto-checksumming service for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
> SHA1 Crypto-checksumming service adapter for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Download and sniff the packets between the boxes using wireshark. You can filter to just see **TCP packets** and make sure that what you see in the packets is NOT clear text.

The data that you see should just look like gibberish - you can even sniff between an unencrypted connection and then compare the packets to the encrypted ones.